# How can Monotonic array problem be solved in Complexity O(n)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

An array is monotonic if it is either increasing or monotone decreasing.

Example:

Input: [1,2,2,3]
Output: true

Input: [3,2,2,1]
Output: true

Input: [1,3,2]
Output: false

Here is my code with O(nlogn) time complexity. I used sorting and an extra array to solve the problem. My code is given below:

```
    bool isMonotonic(vector<int> array) {


    vector<int>extraArray;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<array.size();i++){
        extraArray.push_back(array[i]);
    }
    
    sort(extraArray.begin(),extraArray.end());
    
    for(i=0;i<array.size();i++){
        if(array[i] != extraArray[i])
            break;
    }
    if(i == array.size())
        return true;
    
    for(i = array.size() -1,j=0;j<extraArray.size();i--,j++){
        if(array[i] != extraArray[j])
            break;
    }
    if(j == extraArray.size())
        return true;
    
  return false;
}
```

How can it be solved in O(n) time complexity?

Comment: Have you tried something a little simpler? Like test if an array is increasing. Forget the decreasing aspect for a bit, and maybe inspiration will strike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for O(n) for the monotonic array problem.
We don't need to sort at first with another array. Here, I considered if all the elements are the same, it's still monotonic.

Now if the second element is bigger than the first,  if the whole array needs to be in increasing order, else it can't be monotone. And if the second element is smaller than the first,  if the whole array needs to be in decreasing order. Otherwise, it's not monotonic array.

Be careful of the fact that, first two elements might be same, so we need to iterate through the array to get the difference between two adjacent elements.

Thank you for the hints.

```
bool isMonotonic(vector<int> array) {

    // O(n) time complexity | O(1) space complexity
    
    int i = 0, dif, temp;
            
    while(i+1 < array.size()){  //check until two adjacent elements are different 
     dif = array[i] - array[i+1];
        if(dif == 0)
            i++;
        else
            break;
    }
    
    if(dif == 0){ //all elements are same
        return true; 
    }
    else if(dif > 0){ //decreasing order test
        for( i = i; i+1 < array.size(); i++){
            temp = array[i] - array[i+1];
            if(temp < 0) // if order breaks, it's not monotonic
                break;
        }
    }else{ //dif < 0
        for( i = i; i+1 < array.size(); i++){ //check for increasing order
            temp = array[i] - array[i+1];
            if(temp > 0) //if order breaks, it's not monotonic
                break;
        }
    }
    if( i+1 == array.size() ) //order is maintained through the full array
        return true;
    
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The strategy that you're using works by sorting the array as a substep. That will take time O(n log n) with a standard sorting algorithm, which is the bottleneck in your code. The question is - do you actually need to sort the array to do this?

As a hint, look at the first two elements. If the second element is bigger than the first, then the only way the array is monotone is if the whole array is monotone increasing. Could you check whether that's the case? If the second element is smaller that the first, then the only way the array is monotone is if the whole array is monotone decreasing. Could you check for that? And what should you do if the first two elements are equal?

Answer (score 3):

Some pseudo code:

```
direction = None
for each element in array:
  if increasing(element, next element):
    if direction is decreasing then return false
    else if direction is None, let it be increasing
  else if decreasing(element, next element):
    if direction is increasing then return false
    else if direction is None, let it be decreasing
```